# Mapbox Filter Markers loaded via json

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am looking for solution to add filter (not checkbox) to my site. I have this code loading blank map from Mapbox and added Markers from JSON file. I was trying to add setFilter function, but probably I am using it wrong. I would like to filter items by category property from my JSON file.

```
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = '*************';

  var baseLayer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('test****');
  var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

  // CALL THE GEOJSON HERE
  jQuery.getJSON("locations.geojson", function(data) {

    var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        // USE A CUSTOM MARKER
        layer.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'circle-stroked', 'marker-color': '004E90'}));
        // ADD A POPUP
        layer.bindPopup("<h1>" + feature.properties.title + "</h1><p>" + feature.properties.description + "</p><p><a href=' + feature.properties.website + '>" + feature.properties.website + "</a></p>");
         layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
            this.openPopup();
        });
        layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
            this.closePopup();
        });

      }
    });


    markers.addLayer(geojson);

    // CONSTRUCT THE MAP
    var map = L.map('map', {
        searchControl: {layer: markers},
        zoom: 6,
        center: [51.505, -0.09],
        maxZoom: 13
        })
        .setView([62.965, 19.929], 5)
        .fitBounds(markers.getBounds());

    baseLayer.addTo(map);
    markers.addTo(map);
    L.control.fullscreen().addTo(map);
  });




    </script>
```

Could you please help me add filter buttons (something like here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/filtering-markers)
PS: I think I tried all examples from Mapbox website, yet seems my skills are very limited here.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I was trying to add setFilter function, but probably I am using it wrong. I would like to filter items by category property from my JSON file.

This code example is using `L.geoJson` to load the markers into your map. Like the Mapbox example, you'll need to use `L.mapbox.featureLayer` instead, since it includes the `setFilter` function and `L.geoJson` does not.

Answer (score 0):

tmcw's answer is correct, L.mapbox.featureLayer is confusing

this tutorial helped me!

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-marker-tooltip/